# Matlab : Plot each line of a matrix as a function of its index

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to create a plot with several lines, each corresponding to a row at a given matrix.

To be more elaborate, I have got a matrix *M* where each row represents a value that is changing along the columns. I would like to plot this change as a function of the column index to each of the rows, so to plot (e.g) the first rowI should :

```
plot(M(1,:));
```

The thing is, I would like to plot *all* the rows. Of course I could iterate over them, [hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) and plot the current one:

```
(plot(M(i,:))
```

but I'm wondering if there's a simple command or a single-liner that would do it.

I have tried [plotmatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html) but without much success regarding the desirable results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried  `plot(M')`?

From the first paragraph of the [documentation of `plot`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

> plot(Y) plots the columns of Y versus the index of each value when Y is a real number.

Comment: Yep, pretty simple indeed  :)
Thanks!